# Why the output is not getting printed in the File named EmailList.txt under WEB-INF folder from Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

Here is the my servlet class that is responsible to get the data from the HTML page and store that data in EmailList.txt file placed under WEB-INF directory:

Code Snippet from Servlet class...

```
//Get Parameters from the request object
String firstName=request.getParameter("firstName");
String lastName=request.getParameter("lastName");
String emailId=request.getParameter("emailId");

//Get a relative file name
ServletContext context=getServletContext();
String path=context.getRealPath("WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");

//Use Regular Java object to write the data to the file
UserData userData=new UserData(firstName, lastName, emailId);
UserIO.addUser(userData, path);
```

Where **UserData** is a Regular Java class with *setters* and *getters*, and the **UserIO** contains the *code* for writing the content to the EmailList.txt file

The code for UserIO class is as follows :

```
public class UserIO {

    public static void addUser(UserData userData, 
                               String filePath)
                               throws IOException {

        File file=new File(filePath);

        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

        out.println(userData.getFirstName()+"\t"
                + userData.getLastName()+"\t"
                + userData.getEmailId());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `context.getRealPath("WEB-INF/EmailList.txt")` return? System.out it

Comment: @A4L; it's returning: E:\CodePractice @Enterprise Java\@Eclipse\Murach's Servlet and JSP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Chapter6\WEB-INF\EmailList.txt

Comment: @A4L, I am getting the output when I open the EmailList.txt from above directory, However I am not getting anything when I am opening the file from Eclipse IDE. Any particular reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the file in eclipse an go to properties, you'll see that this is a different file.

Actually you should not try to write/create a file in such a location. Your application may not always be unpacked from a `.war` archive, in which case [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) will return `null`.

An alternative would be to define a [context init parameter](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html#contextParams) in your web.xml and set a *root* for the file system that should be visible to your application

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>fsroot</param-name>
    <param-value>E:\CodePractice</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and to retrieve it anywhere (servlets/JSPs) in your application you can use [`ServletContext#getInitParameter(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter(java.lang.String)):

```java
String path = getServletContext().getInitParameter("fsroot");
```

Comment: Yes you are right, that file actually under my Project folder and it does not contain any data.

Comment: A4L, Thank you very much for your above info. Eventually I got the NullPointerException with my previous approach and then switched to your advice, and now everything is running smoothly.