# Where i Can find text file created by servlet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

This may be a stupid question, but I have to ask because I couldn't find any proper solution.

I am new to Eclipse. I created a Dynamic Web project in Eclipse, In this, I write a simple code to create a text file, Only file name is specified Not the path that where to create, After successful execution, i could not find my text file in my project folder.

If path is specified in the code, I can find the text file in specified directory, My Question is where i can find my text file if i am not specify a path ?

And my code is

```
try {
     FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("user_details.txt", true);
     PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(outFile);
     out1.append(request.getParameter("un"));
     out1.println();
     out1.append(request.getParameter("pw"));
     out1.close();
     outFile.close();
     System.out.println("file created");
} catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println("error in writing a file"+e);
}
```

I edited my code with following lines,

```
String path = new File("user_details.txt").getAbsolutePath(); 

System.out.println(path);
```

The path that i got is below

`D:\Android\eclipse_JE\eclipse\user_details.txt`

Why i got it in the eclipse folder ?

Then,
How can i create a text file in my web app, if this is not the right way  to create a textfile ?

Comment: Do you refresh your project after creating file ?

Comment: Check your project workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 or tmp1 or tmp2 and then go to your project and see there

Comment: yes, i did , but no result

Comment: Sorry, tmp0,tmp1 and tmp2 disappointed me

Comment: i have tried with your source, and file is created in my workspace folder 

>  workspace/MyProject/user_details.txt

Comment: I could not see the text file in my project folder. Then what is my problem ? any guess ?

Comment: @anptk I thought explained that in my answer. You have a `web.xml` file in your web app, put an init-parameter in it and use it as described in the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is located in the actual working directory of your application server. Do a

```
System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutPath());
```

and you'll find the location.

However this is not a good idea to write files in web application like this, because first you never know where it is and second you never know whether you write privilege on it.

You need to specify some *filesystem root* for your application by passing it as `init-parameter` and use it as parent for everything you need to do on the filesystem. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24760217/1113392) to a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24759551/1113392).

You could then create your file like this:

```
String fsroot = getServletContext().getInitParameter("fsroot")
File ud = new File(fsroot, "user_details.txt");
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(ud, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the getAbsolutePath() method.

```
String newFile = new File("Demo.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

It will show the location where the files will be created.