# Where should a java application create files when it is run from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When my Java application is run with "Run application" from Eclipse it needs to create files that persist across multiple runs of the application. Is it an acceptable practice to place these in the "target" directory? For example, workspace//target/database.db.

Are there events that cause eclipse to delete all files in the target directory?

If the target directory is not a good place to store these files where is a good place? It would be awkward to use System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") since the tmpdir is on a different drive and because I would need to mirror the structure of the workspace and project in the tmpdir.

Thank you

Comment: A path somewhere in your user directory would seem appropriate. You can also pass that as a program argument. If you say you need to mirror the structure of the worksapce than your programm seems to be too tightly coupled to that structure.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032311/cant-find-text-file-created-by-servlet-in-eclipse

Comment: I recommend using `System.getProperty("user.home")`. As mentioned below by @user714965

Comment: @user714965 here you go, you are now 10 rep richer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be the OSGi User Area (`-user`, intended for user-specific preferences etc.), or the OSGi Instance Area (`-data`, which is the default home of The Workspace). Take a look at [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html#Locations), and scroll down to "Locations", which explains a bit about these areas.

As for hazardous events, only `-clean` (the Eclipse arg, not the Maven target) and your deployment process come to mind. `-clean` should not touch persisted files but works on the internal caches, only, but you might want to try that out to be sure. Your deployment process might consist of "delete contents of installation directory" plus "copy new stuff to installation directory", which would wipe most of the areas which are by default placed inside the installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

The `target` directory gets deleted when you clean your project (`mvn clean`). That makes this not the best place to store your data. You should better save it to [`System.getProperty("user.home")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), or pass a directory as a program argument as SpaceTrucker mentioned in the comment, that`s also a good solution.