# read/copy file inside dynamic web project in java

Tags: java, servlets

I create a dynamic web app project using JSP/Servlet with eclipse. And I want to create a copy of "db.xls" file in the same place.

I try to create a copy of the "db.xls", the copy will named out.xls but it won't. These files should be located inside the same folder "files". My code compile, db.xls is correctly read, but file out.xls is not created.

What's wrong with my method ? Please help !

```
public void readExcel()
    {
        try{

            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            URL url1 = classLoader.getResource("");

            // read db.xls
            wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(url1.getPath()+"/db.xls"));

            // create a copy of db.xls nammed out.xls
            wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(url1.getPath()+"/out.xls"), wbook);
            shSheet = wwbCopy.getSheet(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image]

I move the file "db.xls" inside WEB-INF and use getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF") but the output file "out.xls" still not created.

```
public void readExcel()
    {
        try{

//          ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
//          URL url1 = classLoader.getResource("");

            String tomcatRoot = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF");

            wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(tomcatRoot+"/db.xls"));
            wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(tomcatRoot+"/out.xls"), wbook);
            shSheet = wwbCopy.getSheet(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` your files and you'll see what's wrong

```
System.out.println(new File(tomcatRoot+"/db.xls").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File(tomcatRoot+"/out.xls").getAbsolutePath());
```

You expect the file to be you project directory but it isnt read/writen from/to that location because you have set up the `files` forlder as `source` folder  in eclipse, so it is part our yours assempbly and lands in the classpath where you can read from a resource, i.e. using classloader and getResource / getResourceAsStream but you cannot and **should not** write to it, for several resons, most obvious is that your web app might not be unpacked from a war files.

In fact, you dont know where you are reading/writing your files to/from.

You might package your file with the war file and read from it, this is correct. But for writing the best is to have an explicite location on the filesystem where you can write your output files. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24760217/1113392) for how you could go abut it using context init parameter

Comment: I use System.out to verify and paths seems to be correct : C:\serveurs\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\wtpwebapps\h2test\WEB-INF\db.xls
C:\serveurs\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\wtpwebapps\h2test\WEB-INF\out.xls.Thanks for the answer!

Comment: C:\serveurs\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\wtpwebapps\h2test\WEB-INF\db.xls
C:\serveurs\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\wtpwebapps\h2test\WEB-INF\out.xls. It works, and the "out.xls" is created locally on my machine. What I really want to do is to use a file such like a database. For example, if I create a new user, the new user will be added to a file. And if I close the application and re-open it, the user is recognized by the application because he's already added to the file "db.xls". How can I do that, please ?

Comment: @cozla, to keep things simple, I guess it's for learning purpose, just save it in a file, but consider what I suggested regarding the directory to use for that, because you cannot rely on the ability to write to `getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF")`. And just use a `csv` instead of `xls`, it is much easier to handle and there is a lot of csv readers out there which are easy to use too.

Answer (score 0):

check the WEB-INF/classes folder, it might be in there

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing write and close statements.
Try:

```
    wwbCopy.write();
    wwbCopy.close();
```

Comment: Thanks I already have these calls but in another method named closeFile()

Answer (score -1):

In order to read files within a web application, the files need to be stored somewhere under the `WEB-INF` folder, otherwise they won't be deployed as part of the application.

Once you've moved the folders into there you can use the following method within a servlet:

```
  String tomcatRoot = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

This will give you the root of the web application. Then you must build the path (including the `WEB-INF` folder) from there:

```
  String sourceFile = tomcatRoot + "/WEB-INF/folder/source.file"
  String targetFile = tomcatRoot + "/WEB-INF/folder/target.file"
```

**EDIT**: I originally stated that `getRealPath()` would give you the `WEB-INF` location. It doesn't, it gives the parent folder.